# Example of non-measurable function

Tags: measurable-functions

Lets take Definition:

[image: Definition measurable function]

Example:

[image]

Then f(x) is not a measurable function, because ${f^{-1}}$({3,4})  $:=$ {1,2} $\not\in \Sigma $.
Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much.